# Fancybox iframe div will not size corretly

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm currently working on a site where I'm using fancybox to open a iframe which contains a php contact form.

It all works alright except the contact php form will not use the whole of the iframe.

I have set the sizes to 800px by 600px and the divs on the contact php are set at 800x600.

When displayed in the iframe they are scrolled at about 150x70px 
here is my script code;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-iframe").fancybox({
        herf        : 'contact/index.html',
        type        : 'iframe',
        margin      : 0,
        padding     : 0,
        width       : 800,
        height      : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : 'false',
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        openSpeed   : 'slow'
    });
});
```

[Here is the link](http://www.lanfinity.org.au/bda/)

Comment: it seems to be working fine now, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah its all good, had conflicting divs